# Turning off windows firewall

Tags: windows, firewall, vps, azure

I did the most idiotic thing I can think off: created a firewall rule for a windows azure VPS to block all incoming traffic, on all ports.

Now I can't access the VPS, obviously.

Any idea how to proceed?

Comment: i assume you need to contact the support and open a ticket for the same. Are you expecting a glitch or a pothhole to work back access to your machine?

Comment: You can either delete the VPS image and start over or roll back the image to an earlier date.

Comment: @Ramhound: I have backup of the data on the VPS but not of the VPS itself. Will take a while(~1 day) to configure it back.

Comment: @pulsarjune: I hope for a glitch, either from azure or from windows server. So far, I am downloading the VPS image, turn the setting off, then upload back and restore. Hopefully this will work

Comment: You want a magic solution, there isn't one, which is the reason you should keep backups of the VPS once its been configured.

Comment: If there were a way to disable the firewall while being locked out by it, I would be very, very, weary!